# how to enter the url from adress bar of the user?

Tags: javascript

how can i make this stuff:
it's SPA, 
user wants to enter URL, like that: 'hello.com#greet/2
but nothing to do, if he surfing on website, on page 'hello.com#greet,
he sees a few greet, and press on 2, then website have url 'hello.com#greet/2' but if he wants to go there from the adress bar, he can't do it, how to solve it? I hope, i explained)

```
function parseHash(phash){
var shash=phash.split("/");
var hash=shash[0].replace("#", "", 1)
var num=shash[1]
return {hash: hash, number: num,}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the queryString from the address bar using `location.hash`, and in the following snippet, I have shown you two ways:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log(window.location.hash);
      console.log(window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("#")));
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#hello">Hello</a>
<a href="#world">World</a>
<a href="#Praveen">Praveen</a>
```

**Update:** I removed the `#` by mistake.

Now based on what you have, you can use the `document`'s `ready` event to get the content from the `location` object and pass it to your custom function to activate the page or tab. Currently I have sent it to the console.